# The functions of the firebase tutorial do not work

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

I tried to implement firebase functions from the tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

This is my code bellow. When I try to call the url https://us-central1-skoon-5ed4d.cloudfunctions.net/addMessage I hava an "Error: could not handle the request"

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
   const original = req.query.text;
   const snapshot = await admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original});
  Firebase console.res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref.toString());

});

exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
  const original = snapshot.val();
  console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.pushId, original);
  const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
  // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
  // writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.
  // Setting an "uppercase" sibling in the Realtime Database returns a Promise.
  return snapshot.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
});
```

I removed async and await and in my log I have Error:

```
Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'messages.original'
    at validateFirebaseData (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1433:15)
    at /srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1479:13
    at Object.forEach (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/util/dist/index.node.cjs.js:837:13)
    at validateFirebaseData (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1462:14)
    at validateFirebaseDataArg (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1421:5)
    at Reference.push (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14087:9)
    at exports.addMessage.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/index.js:23:54)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
    at /worker/worker.js:724:7
    at /worker/worker.js:707:11
```

Comment: Does the error log has more than just Error. could not handle ... ?  You also modified the original code to use async await, did you try using the code the same way it is in the article first before modifying.  The first function you are trying to use can be emulated locally using Firebase serve maybe try that has you will get better log on your system and it will be much faster to debug.

Comment: You don't  send any params, original is then undefined.  You have to call the URL ending with ?text="XXXXXXXXXXX"

Comment: The error is now "first argument contains undefined in property 'messages.original'", which means that you're not passing a value in `req.query.text`.